# Blender - b Why blender is quiting?

Tags: command-line

```
ds@ds-OptiPlex-3040:~$  /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/blender -b
Blender 2.80 (sub 74) (hash 38d4483c6a51 built 2019-07-18 17:31:04)
found bundled python: /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/2.80/python

Blender quit
```

Comment: because you ask it to run in batch mode but don't give it anything to do.

Comment: but -b is for --background @aliasguru

Comment: exactly. See the output of `blender.exe -b --help` for a list of available commands

Comment: Also if I use this one it keeps quiting too:::::: ds@ds-OptiPlex-3040:~$ /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/blender -b -P /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/BlenderRepository/Scripts/HairGenerationScript280.py -P /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/BlenderRepository/Scripts/RenderImage.py

Comment: more info on https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-b` command line option tells Blender to run from the command line. But it expects you to pass on a further sequence of commands. If you don't, Blender just quits because you gave it nothing to do.

Also note that the order of commands matters. `blender -b -S Scene2 filename.blend -a` for instance will open the default scene, then try to switch to Scene2 (which won't exist), then open filename.blend, and then render the frame range defined in the file. After that it quits. `blender -b filename.blend -S Scene2 -a` will on the other hand first open the file filename.blend, THEN switch to Scene2, then render the animation.

See the manual for more information on this matter:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/command_line/launch/index.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: it works, but it doesn't run my script.py::::::::::: ./blender -b -S Scene -P  script.py filename.blend -f 250
@aliasguru

Comment: again, command order matters: It DOES execute your script (I presume it is found, otherwise provide the full path to it), but you run the script BEFORE you open the file. You basically act on the Default Cube scene here.

Comment: Right, now it works, thanks a lot! @aliasguru